# Cómo pasar un programa en python a un .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola yo tengo un programa en python y quiero pasarlo a un exe el problema es que no sé como. Podrian ayudarme?

estos son los módulos que uso:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import pygame,sys,os
import tkinter as tk 
import configparser as cp  
from pygame.locals import *
from numbers import Number
from tendo import singleton
```

Comment: Si sabes un poco de inglés, [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907258/how-do-i-compile-my-python-3-app-to-an-exe) te puede servir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que pruebes:

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Me ha funcionado sin problemas en el pasado.

Comment: no entiendo como puedo decirle que modulos estoy usando

Answer (score 0):

Muchos te recomendarán que te instales py2exe, pero existe una versión online(py2exe.org), funciona con casi todos los programas y módulos